# iOS Getting initial device orientation with accelerometer

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I am working in an OpenGL ES game, c++ and iOS. I would like that the canvas axes be always as in default portait orientation, and also be able to know which is the initial device orientation and all the orientation changes.

The problem I have is that if I configure the XCode project to support the 4 orientations: 2 Portraits and 2 Landscapes, then the Frame which is embedded the OpenGL canvas has the axes depending the initial orientation. If I configure the project to support only Portrait Orientation, then the Application won't tell me if it is in Landscape.

I would like to find a way to do this as much programmatically as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To Know programatically in iOS

```
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    landscapeRight = false;
else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
....
```

2) For Default portrait view

Restrict other orientations in your Xcode project's info.plist

Comment: but if I set the project info.plist orientation to portrait, then [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] is always Portrait idependently if outside the App, it has another orientation

Comment: What do you mean by "Outside the app ?" Do you mean app in BackGround state ? What exactly you need ?

Comment: Yes, I mean in background state. I wanted to set in info.plist to support only Portrait orientation (so the width and height is fixed and it simplfies opengl implementation). I implement the rotations internally in my opengl code, but I can't retrive the inital orientation if I fix Portrait in info.plist .

Comment: In which method you do that code to get the initial orientation ? It doesnt work in didLoad of a View controller.

Comment: You should use that in viewDidAppear and later.